Login Successful using axiosInstance but with bad request 400 and not navigating to dashboard
Frontend handleLogin method from react component Login.jsx which has inputs email and password and login button to handleLogin which calls the Login API from backend email and password are monitored using useState
console is indicating Promise.then at const response = await axiosInstance.post
const handleLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!validateEmail(email)) {
      setError("Please enter a valid email address.");
      return;
    }
    if (!password) {
      setError("Please enter the password");
    }
    setError("");

    try {
      const response = await axiosInstance.post("/login", {
        email: email,
        password: password,
      });
      if (response.data && response.data.accessToken) {
        localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.accessToken);
        navigate("/dashboard");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (
        error.response &&
        error.response.data &&
        error.response.data.message
      ) {
        setError(error.response.data.message);
      } else {
        setError("An unexpected error occured. Please try again.");
      }
    }
  };

Backend Login API, User model has {email, password, _id}
app.post("/login", async (req, res)=>{
    const {email, password} = req.body;
    if(!email){
        return res.status(400).json({message: "Email is required"})
    }
    if(!password){
        return res.status(400).json({message: "Password is required"});
    }
    const userInfo = await User.findOne({email: email});
    if(!userInfo){
        return res.status(400).json({message: "User not found"})
    }
    if(userInfo.email === email && userInfo.password === password){
        const user = {user: userInfo};
        const accessToken = jwt.sign(user, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, {expiresIn: "36000m"});
        return res.status(400).json({
            error: false,
            message: "Login Successful",
            email,
            accessToken,
        });
    }else{
        return res.json({
            error: true,
            message: "Failed to Login",
        })
    }
})

axiosInstance code with BASE_URL as localhost:8000
import axios from 'axios';
import { BASE_URL } from './constants';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    timeout: 10000,
    headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json"
    }
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
        if(accessToken){
            config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
        }
        return config;  
    },
    (error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
)

export default axiosInstance; 

enter image description here
enter image description here
Login happens but with a bad request and in console I get some Promise.then error

Based on the code that you have shared, there is a small problem in it which is causing this 400 bad request.
Your code :
return res.status(400).json({
    error: false,
    message: "Login Successful",
    email,
    accessToken,
});

Here you need to change status(400) to status(200).
